# Pass a private variable to a public static variable c#

Tags: c#, variables, private

I have private int variable called `_scoreTotal`
and I have assign a new public variable called `score` to pass the private varible `_scoreTotal` to the public static `scores`.

So I need to access this value from other script.

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Holoville.HOTween;

/// <summary>
///  This class is the main entry point of the game it should be attached         to a gameobject and be instanciate in the scene
/// Author : Pondomaniac Games
/// </summary>
public class Main : MonoBehaviour {
    public static int score;
    public GameObject _indicator;    //The indicator to know the selected tile
    public GameObject[, ]  _arrayOfShapes;    //The main array that contain all games tiles
    private GameObject _currentIndicator;    //The current indicator to replace and destroy each time the player change the selection
    private GameObject _FirstObject;    //The first object selected
    private GameObject _SecondObject;    //The second object selected
    public GameObject[] _listOfGems;    //The list of tiles we cant to see in the game you can remplace them in unity's inspector and choose all what you want
    public GameObject _emptyGameobject;    //After destroying object they are replaced with this one so we will replace them after with new ones
    public GameObject _particleEffect;    //The object we want to use in the effect of shining stars 
    public GameObject _particleEffectWhenMatch;    //The gameobject of the effect when the objects are matching
    public bool _canTransitDiagonally = false;    //Indicate if we can switch diagonally
    public int _scoreIncrement;    //The amount of point to increment each time we find matching tiles
    private int _scoreTotal = 0;    //The score 
    private ArrayList _currentParticleEffets = new ArrayList();    //the array that will contain all the matching particle that we will destroy after
    public AudioClip MatchSound;    //the sound effect when matched tiles are found
    public int _gridWidth;    //the grid number of cell horizontally
    public int _gridHeight;    //the grid number of cell vertically

                           // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        //Initializing the array with _gridWidth and _gridHeight passed in parameter
        _arrayOfShapes = new GameObject[_gridWidth, _gridHeight];
        //Creating the gems from the list of gems passed in parameter
        for (int i = 0; i <= _gridWidth - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= _gridHeight - 1; j++) {
                var gameObject = GameObject.Instantiate(_listOfGems[Random.Range(0, _listOfGems.Length)] as GameObject, new Vector3(i, j, 0), transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                _arrayOfShapes[i, j] = gameObject;
            }
        }
        //Adding the star effect to the gems and call the DoShapeEffect continuously
        InvokeRepeating("DoShapeEffect", 1f, 0.21F);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        float score = _scoreTotal;
        Main.score++;

        bool shouldTransit = false;
        //Detecting if the player clicked on the left mouse button and also if there is no animation playing
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && HOTween.GetTweenInfos() == null) {

            Destroy(_currentIndicator);
            //The 3 following lines is to get the clicked GameObject and getting the RaycastHit2D that will help us know the clicked object
            //Ray ray   = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
            if (hit.transform != null)
            {  //To know if the user already selected a tile or not yet
                if (_FirstObject == null) _FirstObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
                else {
                    _SecondObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
                    shouldTransit = true;
                }

                _currentIndicator = GameObject.Instantiate(_indicator, new Vector3(hit.transform.gameObject.transform.position.x, hit.transform.gameObject.transform.position.y, -1), transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                //If the user select the second tile we will swap the two tile and animate them
                if (shouldTransit)
                {
                    //Getting the position between the 2 tiles
                    var distance = _FirstObject.transform.position - _SecondObject.transform.position;
                    //Testing if the 2 tiles are next to each others otherwise we will not swap them 
                    if (Mathf.Abs(distance.x) <= 1 && Mathf.Abs(distance.y) <= 1)
                    {   //If we dont want the player to swap diagonally
                        if (!_canTransitDiagonally)
                        {
                            if (distance.x != 0 && distance.y != 0)
                            {
                                Destroy(_currentIndicator);
                                _FirstObject = null;
                                _SecondObject = null;
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        //Animate the transition
                        DoSwapMotion(_FirstObject.transform, _SecondObject.transform);
                        //Swap the object in array
                        DoSwapTile(_FirstObject, _SecondObject, ref _arrayOfShapes);


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _FirstObject = null;
                        _SecondObject = null;

                    }
                    Destroy(_currentIndicator);

                }

            }

        }
        //If no animation is playing
        if (HOTween.GetTweenInfos() == null)
        {
            var Matches = FindMatch(_arrayOfShapes);
            //If we find a matched tiles
            if (Matches.Count > 0)
            {//Update the score
                _scoreTotal += Matches.Count * _scoreIncrement;
                score += Matches.Count * _scoreIncrement;

                foreach(GameObject go in Matches) {
                    //Playing the matching sound
                    GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(MatchSound);
                    //Creating and destroying the effect of matching
                    var destroyingParticle = GameObject.Instantiate(_particleEffectWhenMatch as GameObject, new Vector3(go.transform.position.x, go.transform.position.y, -2), transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                    Destroy(destroyingParticle, 1f);
                    //Replace the matching tile with an empty one
                    _arrayOfShapes[(int)go.transform.position.x, (int)go.transform.position.y] = GameObject.Instantiate(_emptyGameobject, new Vector3((int)go.transform.position.x, (int)go.transform.position.y, -1), transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                    //Destroy the ancient matching tiles
                    Destroy(go, 0.1f);
                }
                _FirstObject = null;
                _SecondObject = null;
                //Moving the tiles down to replace the empty ones
                DoEmptyDown(ref _arrayOfShapes);
            }
            //If no matching tiles are found remake the tiles at their places
            else if (_FirstObject != null
                && _SecondObject != null
                ) {
                //Animate the tiles
                DoSwapMotion(_FirstObject.transform, _SecondObject.transform);
                //Swap the tiles in the array
                DoSwapTile(_FirstObject, _SecondObject, ref _arrayOfShapes);
                _FirstObject = null;
                _SecondObject = null;

            }
        }
        //Update the score
        (GetComponent(typeof(TextMesh))as TextMesh).text = _scoreTotal.ToString();

    }

    // Find Match-3 Tile
    private ArrayList FindMatch(GameObject[, ] cells)
    {//creating an arraylist to store the matching tiles
        ArrayList stack = new ArrayList();
        //Checking the vertical tiles
        for (var x = 0; x <= cells.GetUpperBound(0); x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y <= cells.GetUpperBound(1); y++)
            {
                var thiscell = cells[x, y];
                //If it's an empty tile continue
                if (thiscell.name == "Empty(Clone)") continue;
                int matchCount = 0;
                int y2 = cells.GetUpperBound(1);
                int y1;
                //Getting the number of tiles of the same kind
                for (y1 = y + 1; y1 <= y2; y1++)
                {
                    if (cells[x, y1].name == "Empty(Clone)" || thiscell.name != cells[x, y1].name) break;
                    matchCount++;
                }
                //If we found more than 2 tiles close we add them in the array of matching tiles
                if (matchCount >= 2)
                {
                    y1 = Mathf.Min(cells.GetUpperBound(1), y1 - 1);
                    for (var y3 = y; y3 <= y1; y3++)
                    {
                        if (!stack.Contains(cells[x, y3]))
                        {
                            stack.Add(cells[x, y3]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Checking the horizontal tiles , in the following loops we will use the same concept as the previous ones
        for (var y = 0; y < cells.GetUpperBound(1) + 1; y++)
        {
            for (var x = 0; x < cells.GetUpperBound(0) + 1; x++)
            {
                var thiscell = cells[x, y];
                if (thiscell.name == "Empty(Clone)") continue;
                int matchCount = 0;
                int x2 = cells.GetUpperBound(0);
                int x1;
                for (x1 = x + 1; x1 <= x2; x1++)
                {
                    if (cells[x1, y].name == "Empty(Clone)" || thiscell.name != cells[x1, y].name) break;
                    matchCount++;
                }
                if (matchCount >= 2)
                {
                    x1 = Mathf.Min(cells.GetUpperBound(0), x1 - 1);
                    for (var x3 = x; x3 <= x1; x3++)
                    {
                        if (!stack.Contains(cells[x3, y]))
                        {
                            stack.Add(cells[x3, y]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return stack;
    }

    // Swap Motion Animation, to animate the switching arrays
    void DoSwapMotion(Transform a, Transform b)
    {
        Vector3 posA = a.localPosition;
        Vector3 posB = b.localPosition;
        TweenParms parms = new TweenParms().Prop("localPosition", posB).Ease(EaseType.EaseOutQuart);
        HOTween.To(a, 0.25f, parms).WaitForCompletion();
        parms = new TweenParms().Prop("localPosition", posA).Ease(EaseType.EaseOutQuart);
        HOTween.To(b, 0.25f, parms).WaitForCompletion();
    }


    // Swap Two Tile, it swaps the position of two objects in the grid array
    void DoSwapTile(GameObject a, GameObject b, ref GameObject[, ] cells)
    {
        GameObject cell = cells[(int)a.transform.position.x, (int)a.transform.position.y];
        cells[(int)a.transform.position.x, (int)a.transform.position.y] = cells[(int)b.transform.position.x, (int)b.transform.position.y];
        cells[(int)b.transform.position.x, (int)b.transform.position.y] = cell;
    }

    // Do Empty Tile Move Down
    private void DoEmptyDown(ref GameObject[, ] cells)
    {   //replace the empty tiles with the ones above
        for (int x = 0; x <= cells.GetUpperBound(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= cells.GetUpperBound(1); y++)
            {

                var thisCell = cells[x, y];
                if (thisCell.name == "Empty(Clone)")
                {

                    for (int y2 = y; y2 <= cells.GetUpperBound(1); y2++)
                    {
                        if (cells[x, y2].name != "Empty(Clone)")
                        {
                            cells[x, y] = cells[x, y2];
                            cells[x, y2] = thisCell;
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                }

            }
        }
        //Instantiate new tiles to replace the ones destroyed
        for (int x = 0; x <= cells.GetUpperBound(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= cells.GetUpperBound(1); y++)
            {
                if (cells[x, y].name == "Empty(Clone)")
                {
                    Destroy(cells[x, y]);
                    cells[x, y] = GameObject.Instantiate(_listOfGems[Random.Range(0, _listOfGems.Length)] as GameObject, new Vector3(x, cells.GetUpperBound(1) + 2, 0), transform.rotation) as GameObject;

                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x <= cells.GetUpperBound(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= cells.GetUpperBound(1); y++)
            {

                TweenParms parms = new TweenParms().Prop("position", new Vector3(x, y, -1)).Ease(EaseType.EaseOutQuart);
                HOTween.To(cells[x, y].transform, .4f, parms);
            }
        }



    }
    //Instantiate the star objects
    void DoShapeEffect()
    {
        foreach(GameObject row in _currentParticleEffets)
            Destroy(row);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            _currentParticleEffets.Add(GameObject.Instantiate(_particleEffect, new Vector3(Random.Range(0, _arrayOfShapes.GetUpperBound(0) + 1), Random.Range(0, _arrayOfShapes.GetUpperBound(1) + 1), -1), new Quaternion(0, 0, Random.Range(0, 1000f), 100)) as GameObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static field can not reference an instance field. What you can do is change _scoreTotal to be a public static.

However it seems like you design is flawed - if you have two instances of Main then you can only have ONE static score variable but TWO _scoreTotal. To which one would you reference? If you can only have one instance of Main then consider changing all your variables to static or make it a Singleton.